# Load/Save sorting & filter options on DataTables using Laravel

Tags: jquery, laravel, laravel-5, datatables, yajra-datatable

I need to save the state of pagination, sorting & search inputs, ultimately utilizing Laravel and an API instead of the database. I'd rather not use `yajra/laravel-datatables` as I've already created the complex DataTable I need.

**Example**

```js
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var table = $('#stackoverflow-datatable').DataTable({
            "stateSave": true,
            "stateSaveCallback": function (settings, data) {
                $.ajax({
                    "url": "/api/save_state",
                    "data": data,
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "success": function (response) {}
                });
            },
            "stateLoadCallback": function (settings) {
                var o;
                $.ajax({
                    "url": "/api/load_state",
                    "async": false,
                    "dataType": "json",
                    "success": function (json) { o = json; }
                });
                return o;
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

The URLs: "/api/load_state" point to a Laravel route, and the routes point to specific methods on the Controller. I see that it's calling the methods correctly. However, I don't know what it's sending me or how I change the JS to tell it to give me what I need. Once I have an on Object (or something), send it back and apply it when the user goes back to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By the description, looks like you have everything working, you just need a way to debug data you are receive, so you can use Log to do that:

```
Route::get('/api/load_state', function() {
    \Log::info(app('request')->all());
});
```

And tail the log

```
tail -f storage/logs/laravel.log
```

So if you hit

```
http://domain.dev/api/load_state?what=1
```

You should see

[image]

To respond a json object back to the client, you can do

```
Route::get('/api/load_state', function(Request $request) {
    return response()->json(
        User::find($request->get('user_id'))
    );
});
```

Comment: Ah, yes! Thank you so much! So essentially I can do the same thing with the router pointed to this method...

    public function saveState(Request $request)
    {
        Log::info($request->all());
    }

And save the data but once I have the stored data available how do I use "load_state" and it's Laravel method to pull data into the datatable and sync up everything?

Comment: This works great, THANK YOU! I json_encode()/json_decoded the object so I could get it into the database. The one thing the object doesn't seem to include, however, are my custom filters which are really important for loading/saving. Any ideas on that? I just assumed they'd be part of that object.

Comment: Please show more of your code so we can understand what you are doing and how you are doing it now.

Comment: This is a pure Datatables JS/HTML question and perhaps this belongs in an entirely new post. But if you have a field outside of your table like $('#dateStart'). How do you add this custom filter to the datatable in a way so that it's part of the "search" in the object that can be saved/loaded? My JS above has not changed so there's no other code to show you.

Comment: I added the new question if you know the answer, Cheers. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040855/adding-custom-search-fields-to-a-datatable-object